# Swift I can't append two different strings on the same array

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I have an API call that brings an array of CustomDescription. Each element of this array has a name, so, I created the following:

1. A string array named namArray
2. A for loop that runs my CustomDescription array, and append it's elements to namArray.

My problem comes when I print my namArray after my for loop, and it just shows one element inside the array, it doesn't append the elements corresponding to the calls.

Here is my code:

```
func getTypes(typesUrl: String, handler: @escaping([CustomDescription]) -> Void) {
    
    AF.request(typesUrl).validate().responseTypes { (types) in
        
        guard let typeData = types.value,
              let typeNames = typeData.names else { return }
        
        var namArray = [String]()
        
        for name in typeNames {
            
            guard let types = name.name else { return }
            
            if name.language?.name == "es" {
                namArray.append(types)
            }
        }
        
        print(namArray)
        handler(typeNames)
    }
}
```

And my console logs the following:

```
You've got 94 species successfully
["Planta"]
["Veneno"]
```

I want to get ["Planta", "Veneno"] instead, but can't figure out how.

Comment: did you try make it global ( putting out of the function) var namArray = [String]()

Comment: It works, but (i'm working with pokemons in a CollectionView) when I tap a pokemon, it keeps adding names, and I just need the one or two names assigned to each pokemon type (not all pokes has two types).

Comment: what does it mean it works ?

Comment: For the guard statement inside the loop did you meant to do `return` instead of `continue`?